# Java Spring Boot Actuator Metrics system load average returning -1

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I am a new user to Spring Boot Actuator Metrics, I need to determine the CPU utilization of the system. The /metrics url does give me rest of the details, however the systemload.average returns -1 (if load average is not available -1 is returned). Could you let me know where I went wrong and how do I correct it?
I am using maven and Eclipse IDE (Mars). I am accessing metric details on localhost itself. the url is http://localhost:8080/details/metrics (details used for context path)

Here is my code:
Application.java file
package spring.boot.admin.actuator;

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;

@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:application.properties")
public class Application{

public static void main(final String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
}
}
```

POM File

4.0.0

```
  <groupId>spring.boot.admin</groupId>
  <artifactId>actuator</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>actuator</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

<parent>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
<version>1.3.7.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
    
  </dependencies>
</project>

**application.properties file**

management.port=8080
management.context-path=/details
management.security.enabled=true

endpoints.health.enabled=false

security.basic.enabled=true
security.user.name=admin
security.user.password=admin

endpoints.health.id=health
endpoints.health.sensitive=true
endpoints.health.enabled=true

endpoints.metrics.id=metrics
endpoints.metrics.sensitive=true
endpoints.metrics.enabled=true

endpoints.server.id=server
endpoints.server.sensitive=false
endpoints.server.enabled=true

endpoints.info.id=info
endpoints.info.sensitive=false
endpoints.info.enabled=true
info.app.name=Spring Actuator Example
info.app.description=Spring Actuator Working Examples
info.app.version=0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
management.security.enabled=true
```

[image]

Comment: The [code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/endpoint/SystemPublicMetrics.java#L97) is using JMX. Can you try to see with VisualVM what is returned there?

Comment: @WimDeblauwe thanks for the advice, it gave a bit more clarity about the JMX to me. I used VisualVM now(for the first time) , it shows a thread as JMX Server Connection Timeout 221 in wait state , whereas JMX Cient Heartbeat 10 thread in sleep state.

Comment: You need to install the 'VisualVM-MBeans' plugin. After that, there will be a new tab 'MBeans'. There, open the 'java.lang' folder and select 'OperatingSystem' in the tree. On the right side, you will see 'SystemLoadAverage' in the table.

Comment: @WimDeblauwe I tried the steps, the Systemload.Average is -1 in VisualVm

Answer (score 2):

The `systemload.average` returns what the JVM returns through the OperatingSystem MBean (Available in the `java.lang` tree node). Use JConsole or the VisualVM-Beans plugin in VisualVM to view what is returned there.

If the value of the `SystemLoadAverage` attribute is the same, it is no bug in Spring Boot or your usage of Spring Boot.

Comment: @WimDeblauve are there any alternatives to find systemload.average using Spring boot actuator instead of getting -1, since my initial goal is to find the system load average? Or any changes that could be made ?

Comment: On what operating system are you running?

Comment: Windows 7 Enterprise Edition