# Metrics for CPU usage and Utilization using Spring Boot Dropwizard

Tags: spring, cpu-usage, dropwizard, codahale-metrics, utilization

Is there a way to measure CPU usage and Utilization of different aspects (CPU, Thread, Memory etc) using `dropwizard` in `spring-boot`?

Answer (score 2):

Use `spring-boot-actuator` for that. There is already a `/metrics` endpoint for the data you are asking for.

Check `systemload.average`, `mem`, `mem.free`, `threads` etc for the exact information.

For more information check:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-metrics.html
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-metrics.html#production-ready-dropwizard-metrics

> A default `MetricRegistry` Spring bean will be created when you declare
>   a dependency to the `io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-core` library; you
>   can also register you own `@Bean` instance if you need customizations.
>   Users of the Dropwizard ‘Metrics’ library will find that Spring Boot
>   metrics are automatically published to
>   `com.codahale.metrics.MetricRegistry`. Metrics from the `MetricRegistry`
>   are also automatically exposed via the `/metrics` endpoint
>
> When Dropwizard metrics are in use, the default `CounterService` and
>   `GaugeService` are replaced with a `DropwizardMetricServices`, which is a
>   wrapper around the `MetricRegistry` (so you can `@Autowired` one of those
>   services and use it as normal). You can also create “special”
>   Dropwizard metrics by prefixing your metric names with the appropriate
>   type (i.e. timer.*, histogram.* for gauges, and meter.* for counters).

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I am using `metrics` endpoint, but how do I arrive at the % values for utilization? can I assess the system by seeing just the number for threads.* unless I can tally the numbers with max possible values? I can't find them. I always get `"systemload.average": -1`

Comment: Also, how to find `cpu` utilization?

Comment: Check this for the -1 systemload.average: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39654056/java-spring-boot-actuator-metrics-system-load-average-returning-1 I don't think you can see the max possible value for threads. I think you can only get percentages for the memory and heap information and even then you should calculate it out for yourself.The systemload.average should be responsible for the cpu utilization.